# Algo to return a vector of available time slots for scheduling a meeting between two persons

Tags: c++, strings, vectors

There are 2 persons and their already booked meeting schedule is given and also time bound for both the person is given. Now, we want to schedule a meeting between them in an available time that suits both of them. And at the end we want to return the available time slots for the new meeting.
Given input:

```
vector<pair<string,string>>p1={{"09:00","10:30"},{"12:00","13:00"},{"16:00","18:00"}};
pair<string,string>b1={"09:00","20:00"};
vector<pair<string,string>>p2={{"10:00","11:30"},{"12:30","14:30"},{"14:30","15:00"},{"16:00","17:00"}};
pair<string,string>b2={"10:00","18:30"};
int d = 30;
```

where p1 is the schedule and b1 is the time bound(only wants the meeting in that bound) for person 1 and p2 and b2 for person 2. d is the duration of the meeting in minutes.

Output:

```
[11:30,12:00] , [15:00,16:00] , [18:00,18:30]
```

These are the available time slots for the meeting. I have written the code and i want to know if i have written any duplicate code and if it is a good approach.The code is really long

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool comparator(string s1,string s2){
    
    int hour1 = stoi(s1.substr(0,2));
    int min1 = stoi(s1.substr(3,2));
    int hour2 = stoi(s2.substr(0,2));
    int min2 = stoi(s2.substr(3,2));
    
    if(((hour1*60)+min1)>=((hour2*60)+min2)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int difftime(string s1,string s2){
    int ans=0;
    int hour1 = stoi(s1.substr(0,2));
    int min1 = stoi(s1.substr(3,2));
    int hour2 = stoi(s2.substr(0,2));
    int min2 = stoi(s2.substr(3,2));
    
    ans = (hour2*60)+min2-(hour1*60)+min1;
    return ans;
}

vector<pair<string,string>> solve(vector<pair<string,string>>p1,vector<pair<string,string>>p2,pair<string,string>b1,pair<string,string>b2,int time){
    
    vector<pair<string,string>>result;
    int p1size=p1.size();
    int p2size=p2.size();
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(i<p1size && j<p2size){   // O(n)    or o(m)
        if(comparator(p1[i].first,p2[j].first)){
            result.push_back({p2[j].first,p2[j].second});
            j++;
        }
        else{
            result.push_back({p1[i].first,p1[i].second});
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    while(i<p1.size()){  //o(n-m)
        result.push_back({p1[i].first,p1[i].second});
        i++;
    }
    while(j<p2.size()){     //o(m-n)
        result.push_back({p2[j].first,p2[j].second});
        j++;
    }
    
    string start_max,end_min;
    
    if(comparator(b1.first,b2.first)){
        start_max = b1.first;
    }
    else{
        start_max = b2.first;
    }
    if(comparator(b1.second,b2.second)){
        end_min= b2.second;
    }
    else{
        end_min= b1.second;
    }
    vector<pair<string,string>>output;
    i=0;
    string max_end_time = result[0].second;
    
    while(i<result.size()-1){       //o(n+m)
        if(comparator(result[i].second,result[i+1].first)){
            result[i+1].first = result[i].first;
        }
        
        if(comparator(result[i+1].second,max_end_time) && comparator(end_min,result[i+1].second)){
            max_end_time = result[i+1].second;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<result.size()-1;i++){     //o(n+m)
        if(difftime(result[i].second,result[i+1].first)>=time){
            if(comparator(result[i].second,start_max) && comparator(end_min,result[i+1].first)){
                output.push_back(make_pair(result[i].second,result[i+1].first));
            }
        }
        
    }
    if(difftime(max_end_time,end_min)>=time){
        output.push_back(make_pair(max_end_time,end_min));
    }
    return output;
}



int main(){
    vector<pair<string,string>>p1={{"09:00","10:30"},{"12:00","13:00"},{"16:00","18:00"},{"19:00","20:00"}};
    pair<string,string>b1={"09:00","20:00"};
    vector<pair<string,string>>p2={{"10:00","11:30"},{"12:30","14:30"},{"14:30","15:00"},{"16:00","17:00"}};
    pair<string,string>b2={"10:00","18:30"};
    int d = 30;
    
    
    
    
    vector<pair<string,string>>a = solve(p1,p2,b1,b2,d);
    
    for(auto it:a){
        cout<<"["<<it.first<<","<<it.second<<"]"<<" , ";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Edward I have made some changes in the code and i guess it works fine now. I have tried to run it in several test cases and its giving the output.

Comment: As currently in the question, the code produces "[09:00,10:30] , [09:00,11:30] , [12:00,13:00] , [12:00,14:30] , [12:00,15:00] , [16:00,17:00] , [16:00,18:00] , [19:00,20:00] , [11:30,12:00] , [15:00,16:00] , [18:00,18:30] , " which is not the given answer, "[11:30,12:00] , [15:00,16:00] , [18:00,18:30]"

Comment: @Edward ohh, sorry about that I forgot to comment out some parts. It now just returns the actual answer now

Comment: OK, now it's working.  I've retracted my close vote and look forward to reviewing the code.

Answer (score 4):

I see a number of things which may help you improve your program.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use more whitespace to enhance readability of the code

Instead of crowding things together like this:

```
if(difftime(result[result.size()-1].second,end_min)>=time){
```

most people find it more easily readable if you use more space:

```
if (difftime(result[result.size() - 1].second, end_min) >= time) {
```

### Use descriptive names

The use of `std::pair` is not terrible here, but it would be easier to understand the code if, instead of the somewhat cryptic `first` and `second` data items that `std::pair` provides, we could use `starttime` and `endtime`.  Also the use of `b1`, `p1`, etc. are not at all descriptive and should be replaced with more meaningful names.  Also `comparator` is very vague.  I'd probably change the sense and call it `IsLessThan`.  But we can do better as I'll show later.

### Simplify boolean expressions

The last lines of `comparator()` are these:

```
if(((hour1*60)+min1)>=((hour2*60)+min2)){
        return true;
}
return false;
```

We can simplify that by using the expression evaluation directly:

```
return hour1 * 60 + min1 >= hour2 * 60 + min2;
```

### Use appropriate `#include`s

The code is using `std::string` but does not `#include <string>`.  It's good to make sure to include all of the appropriate headers because even though it might compile on your compiler right now (because one of the headers you have listed includes one that you haven't) it isn't going to be portable and could break with the next compiler update.

### Use a more appropriate object

Rather than `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` what you really need is a start time and end time.  C++ includes the [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library which would make this code much simpler and easier to understand and also more efficient: whenever the code compares two times at the moment, it does the conversion to minutes each time!  An alternative would be to use your own custom type for this, which is the approach I'll illustrate here.  First a class called `mytime` handles the conversions to and from text and internally stores the time in minutes.  We also define an `operator<` and an `operator-` that will be handy later.  It would be better to provide some more rigorous error checking for the input strings, but I'll leave that enhancement to you.

```
class mytime {
public:
    mytime(const std::string& timestring) {
        minute = std::stoi(timestring.substr(0, 2)) * 60 + std::stoi(timestring.substr(3, 2));
    }
    mytime() = default;
    bool operator<(const mytime& other) const { return minute < other.minute; }
    unsigned operator-(const mytime& other) const { return minute - other.minute; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const mytime& t) {
        return out << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << t.minute / 60
            << ':' << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << t.minute % 60;
    }
private:
    unsigned minute = 0;
};
```

Now instead of the `std::pair`, let's create a `struct timerange`:

```
struct timerange {
    timerange(const std::string& start, const std::string& finish) : start{start}, finish{finish} {};
    timerange(mytime start, mytime finish) : start{start}, finish{finish} {};
    bool operator<(const timerange& other) const { return start < other.start; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const timerange& tr) {
        return out << "[" << tr.start << "," << tr.finish << "]";
    }
    mytime start;
    mytime finish;
};
```

### Use a more efficient algorithm

We can accomplish the goal while doing only a single traversal through the arrays.  First, let's convert `b1` and `b2` to appointments span the beginning and the ending of the day.  Here's one way to do that:

```
static const timerange day{"00:00", "24:00"};
p1.emplace_back(day.start, b1.start);
p2.emplace_back(day.start, b2.start);
p1.emplace_back(b1.finish, day.finish);
p2.emplace_back(b2.finish, day.finish);
std::sort(p1.begin(), p1.end());
std::sort(p2.begin(), p2.end());
```

Note that this explicitly sorts both appointment lists, which also takes care of the problem of unsorted input.  Now we can sweep through both vectors using iterators and simply end when either list runs out of appointments.

```
std::vector<timerange> solution{};
auto one{p1.begin()};
auto two{p2.begin()};
for (mytime curr{}; one != p1.end() && two != p2.end(); ) {
    if (curr < one->start) { // one is free 
        if (curr < two->start) { // two is also free
            if (std::min(one->start, two->start) - curr >= minutes_duration) {
                solution.emplace_back(curr, std::min(one->start, two->start));

            }
            curr = std::max(one->finish, two->finish);
            ++one;
            ++two;
        } else { // two is busy
            // advance curr to end of current appointment
            curr = two->finish;
            ++two;
        }
    } else { // one is busy
       if (two->start < curr) { // two is free
            curr = one->finish;
        } else {  // two is busy
            curr = std::max(one->finish, two->finish);
            ++two;
        }
        ++one;
    }
}
return solution;
```

Note that because we defined `operator<`, we can easily do the comparisons and sorting and can use `std::min` and `std::max` with no further effort or coding.  Now the usage in `main` is extremely simple:

```
const auto a = solve(p1, p2, b1, b2, d);
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<timerange>(std::cout, ", "));
```